# Can I use the new CSS Custom Properties (Variables) with Bulma?

Tags: javascript, bulma, css-variables

Bulma uses [Sass variables](https://bulma.io/documentation/customize/variables/). I watched a tutorial about [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var) and they have features I would like to use. Can I use CSS variables with Bulma?

I'm new to web development and deciding now whether to use Bulma in a Node.js project.

Reference:
[What is the difference between CSS variables and preprocessor variables? | CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/difference-between-types-of-css-variables/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah. You can. Although css variables is not supported by all browsers. Use [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=css%20variables) to check the available browsers it is supported on and also the usage percentage in your country